# C# WPF - Display Data during SQL Execution

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, datagrid, db2

Ok so I have a SQL DB2 connection that runs a query and stores the results into a DataTable. This DataTable is then loaded into a DataGrid. The query is also running in it's own thread and uses a dispatcher to update the UI.

Here is my Code Example:

```
using(DB2Connection conn = new DB2Connection("xyz"))
{
    string DB2Query = query;
    if(conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) conn.Open();
    DB2Command cmd = new DB2Command(DB2Query, conn);
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    DB2DataAdapter adapter = new DB2DataAdapter(cmd);

    DataTable ds = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(ds);
    this.Dispatcher.Invoce((Action)(() =>
    {
        Data.ItemsSource = ds.DefaultView;
        Results.SelectedItem = Results.Items.GetItemAt(0);
        Errors.Text = "Query Ran Successfully!!! \n" + "Total Rows: " + ds.Rows.Count;
    }));
    conn.Dispose();
    conn.Close();
}
```

My question is this... If I have a query that pulls 1,000,000 rows, and I want to push every 10,000 rows the data that is collected how do I do this? Simply put, How do I bind results to a datagrid while the query is still running?

If you have a solution for sql-server I assume it will work for a DB2Connection as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind your `DataGrid` to an `ObservableCollection` (or better yet to `CollectionViewSource` which is a view of that `ObservableCollection`), not to the `DataTable` and as you add a batch of items to the `ObservableCollection` your `DataGrid` will be automatically updated to display new items.

Comment: Ok so if I go this route how do I update the ObservableCollection with the results of the query? Is there a way to have a SQLConnection or DB2Conneciton send data back midway through it's query?

Comment: You could use the BackgroundWorker, tell it how ofter to report about the progress of the operation and in its ReportProgress Method update your ObservableCollection...